# delete more than 1 records using single prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I am executing two prepared statement for deleting two records of different id. i want to delete both records in a single prepared statement execution
my code is like this

```
String sqlDelete,sqlSelect2;
  sqlDelete = "delete from vul_detail where scanno=? and id=?";//
            PreparedStatement ps2=conn.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
//  System.out.println("PS Created Successfully");
  ps2.setString(1, "scan_2");
  ps2.setInt(2, 2);
 // ps2.setInt(3, 5);
  ps2.executeUpdate();
  System.out.println("first record deleted");
  ps2.setString(1, "scan_2");
  ps2.setInt(2, 5);
  ps2.executeUpdate();
  System.out.println("second record deleted");
     sqlSelect2="select * from vul_detail;"; 
           stmt=conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("select query created");
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelect2);
```

I tried query as

```
sqlDelete = "delete from vul_detail where scanno=? and id=?,?";
PreparedStatement ps2=conn.prepareStatement(sqlDelete);
System.out.println("PS Created Successfully");
 ps2.setString(1, "scan_2");
 ps2.setInt(2, 2);
 ps2.setInt(3, 5);
 ps2.executeUpdate();
```

I am getting exception in this please help

Comment: You already got an answer that should fix this issue (since it's quite obvious). But please remember to include the exception in future questions instead of just saying "I am getting exception".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the "IN" condition is:

```
expression in (value1, value2, .... value_n);
```

In your example:

```
sqlDelete = "delete from vul_detail where scanno = ? and id in (?, ?)";
```